# Can all question words be followed by "the hell"?

Tags: grammar, emphasis

1. What the hell did I marry?
2. Why the hell did I marry?
3. When the hell did I marry?
4. Where the hell did I marry?
5. ...

Can all question words be followed by "the hell"?

Comment: Google Books says it has over 20,000 instances of ["whence did you..."](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whence+did+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but it seems quite possible to me no-one has ever even *said*, let alone written, *"whence the hell did you..."*. Apart from that, I think the question is General Reference.

Comment: @tchrist- Isn't that "*Whither the hell didst thou...?*"

Comment: Methinks thou hast been trumped, tchrist! (can't stop laughing!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, yes, but there are restrictions on register.  The following is weird (`??`), because *whom* is high register, *the hell*, low:

> ?? Whom the hell did you see?

Comment: Haha have an upvote for finding another "register mismatch". But I would just say I found quite a few instances of ["Whom the hell"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Whom+the+hell%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. Admittedly, many of them are either puns on *for whom the **bell** tolls*, or involve mistaken use of *whom* instead of *who*, but it's not completely unknown. So I stand by ***whence** the hell...*, which apparently *never* occurs.

Comment: That’s great.  I was going to add _Whither the hell ..._ to my answer when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

> Which the hell did you take?

I don't think that works, which would make the answer "no".

Comment: Well, but on the day after his first wedding Jacob may very well have asked "Which the hell did I marry?"

Comment: At a crossroads in a strange town. "Which the hell way do we go now". But it doesn't sound good.

Comment: I think because "the hell" implies you have absolutely no idea what the answer is, but "which" means you have only a limited set of choices. Those tend to work against each other.